# How can page-object-gem be used with IRB?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

Using watir-webdriver, you can test your code while developing using IRB (interactive ruby).
But this does not seem to work when using the page-object gem.
When I run the ruby program, I can see my page-object calls are working.
This is not apparent from IRB. E.g. Here's what I type in IRB:

```
require 'page-object'
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

I then manually navigate to the page I want and go back to IRB:

```
b.table(:id => 'manage-groups-list').present?
```

IRB returns true. So, watir-webdriver knows the table control is present on the page. Can we do the same thing in page-object? 
Continue coding in IRB:

```
class ManageGroupsPage
include PageObject
table(:groupsList, :id => 'manage-groups-list')
end
```

I then try to get the contents of the table from IRB. However, this returns an error:

```
irb(main):021:0> puts ManageGroupsPage.groupsList.to_s
NoMethodError: undefined method `groupsList' for ManageGroupsPage:Class
from (irb):21
from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I am using page-object 1.0.3, watir-webdriver 0.6.11 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at their [basic usage](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object#basic-usage) docs, it seems like calling

```
table :groupsList, id: 'manage-groups-list'
```

generates an instance method rather than a class method. So you would need to call the generated method like so:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
page = ManageGroupsPage.new(b) # build a new page object
page.groupsList # call the instance method
```

Comment: This works well thanks. It's a shame there's so much more typing with PageObject than using watir-webdriver directly. It's also a hassle if you forget to declare a control in your class - because you can't edit the class from IRB; you have to restart and repeat everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the 'pry' gem. Add to your env file, `require 'pry'` and then where ever you want the code to stop/inspect, add `binding.pry`